# Dynamic Autofill

Tags: dynamic, autofill

I am trying to write a VBA to Autofill Columns H to K based on the amount of lines populated in column A.  I also need this to start at a different row everytime I run the macro.  Alos note that my worksheet is not named sheet1 or sheet2 (I don't know if this makes a difference)

I have nothing that works so far.

Sub Macro1

```
Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
x = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(3)(1).row
For i = 8 To 11
Cells(2, i).AutoFill Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(x, i)), xlFillDefault
Next i
```

End Sub

This doesn't work.  It doesn't autofill any column.

Comment: post, what you tried so far and what exactly didn't work

Comment: Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
x = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(3)(1).row
For i = 8 To 11
Cells(2, i).AutoFill Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(x, i)), xlFillDefault
Next i

It starts at row 1 and my row 1 is blank so it is copying down blanks for my entire columns.